# misconstrue as mispresent/mislead

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can *misconstrue* be used to mean misrepresent/mislead?

Looking at the definition https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misconstrue it only offers the side of the observer, ie as something being misinterpreted, but can it also be used to mean something more akin to mislead?

for example: "The author intentionally *misconstrued* the events to make it seem like the socialists were to blame"

I think I have seen it used like this but cannot find it documented after a quick search.

Comment: I feel like I've seen it too, and my reaction is that it works, i.e. implies the purpose of misleading, in the same way that "intentionally misinterpret" would do the same thing.  I don't think it crosses over into the oxymoronic and/or ironic territory of "intentionally misunderstand."

Comment: “You’ve misconstrued that, senator, and you’ve done that repeatedly in the past.”
Dr. Fauci pushes back against Sen. Rand Paul’s claims on the coronavirus.https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=420945955538333

Comment: It is something of a euphemism for "You twisted my words".

Comment: The question here is a bit confusing.  It's clear that "intentionally misconstrue" would imply that some misleading is afoot.  That's the example you offer.  But if your real question is whether the bare word "misconstrue" (without the modifier) suggests misleading, perhaps it's not as obvious.

Comment: I have seen this too and it is jarring. Misconstrue means `misinterpreting`,  and not misleading. In case of Dr Fauci, my understanding was that the senator deliberately misinterpreted something and then went on to spread misinformation using his  interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

> **misconstrue** *verb*
> Interpret (a person's words or actions) wrongly.
> ‘my advice was deliberately misconstrued’
> ‘I worry that this advice may be misconstrued, especially at a time when the news is full of journalistic imperfections.’
> [-Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/misconstrue?locale=en)

The definition and examples indicate that *misinterpretation* is the basic sense of the word.

However, the context can convey a negative connotation. When the misinterpretation is deliberate, the sense is definitely negative.

As to whether it carries the sense of leading someone else to the wrong conclusion, that is a secondary sense depends on the context. It is possible, but one can also *deliberately misconstrue* an instruction simply to justify their own behaviour (not to influence someone else). The secondary sense is not rooted in the word *misconstrue* but the motivation for the misinterpretation.

Comment: Looking at the definitions in the OED, I don't think you can *deliberately misconstrue* something to/for yourself, only, e.g., for the benefit/detriment of others, like *misunderstand* or *misread*. I can deliberately misread something aloud, but I know I am misreading.

Comment: @DjinTonic Not "to/for yourself", but "to justify their own behaviour". It's not a matter of reading something "aloud", but interpreting something in a way that was not intended or even contrary to intent.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is that just lying/pretending to misconstrue? Can you give an example?

Comment: @DjinTonic I’ll be charitable and take the offensive part of your comment as a joke. Example: if someone saw a sign saying “No- swimming in pool” and swam anyway, they might try to justify themselves by pointing to a puddle nearby and saying that they didn’t swim in that. We’d say they understood the sign and _purposely misconstrued_ it.

Comment: My sincere apology to you if thought I meant you were lying! I meant, in fact, that the person who purposely misconstrues is *lying to others or themselves*. My point is that to give that sense to *misconstrue* you must qualify it. Does your example work if you leave out purposely? That is what the OP is asking with "Can misconstrue be used to mean misrepresent/mislead," correct? In other words can you use "to break" something to mean "to almost break" something without the qualifier?

Comment: @DjinTonic Oh dear, please accept _my_ apologies; I’ve inadvertently misconstrued your comment. Yes, I agree that using the word to mean _lying_ tends to require explicit markers. On its own, the natural sense of _misconstrue_ tends to default to just a neutral _misunderstanding_.

Comment: Ordinarily, I’d suggest deleting comments to tidy up, now that things have been cleared up. However, the comments illustrate the use of the term _misconstrue_ (in the innocent sense) quite nicely, so it would be useful to leave them standing in this case.

Comment: *deliberately misconstrue* usually involves taking advantage of an ambiguity, and deliberately choosing an interpretation different from the speaker's intent, in order to get away with something.